# hibernate, mix load with criteria possible?

Tags: hibernate, generics

is it possible to mix a `session.load(class, id)` with a flexible criteria (criteria api)?

I need something like :

```
select * from entity where id = 1 AND name = 'miller'
```

I use the generic approach for the find by `id`:

```
public T findById(ID id, boolean lock) {
    T entity;
    if (lock)
        entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id, LockMode.UPGRADE);
    else
        entity = (T) getSession().load(getPersistentClass(), id);

    return entity;
}
```

and would like to extend this by

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
    criteria.add( Restrictions.eq("name", "miller"));
```

`where ("name", "miller")` will be replaced by something generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load and criteria can't be mixed. Load creates a proxy if the instance isn't in cache yet. The purpose of load (and get) is that its arguments are the keys for the cache (class and id) and it doesn't need to flush the session before. Criteria is a kind of query. When you already know the id, you don't need a query anymore. I mean, does `id = 1 AND name = 'miller'` make any sense?

---

Just write you own "Get":

```
public TEntity secureGet<TEntity>(int id, string user)
{
  // avoid flushing, only when you never expect that the user name
  // in the object to be loaded has changed within the current session.
  // this is very performance relevant.
  session.flushMode = FlushMode.Never;
  return session
    .createCriteria(typeof(TEntity))
    .add( Restrictions.idEq(id))
    .add( Restrictions.eq("name", user))
    .UniqueResult<TEntity>();
  session.flushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
}
```

(Sorry for possible syntactic errors, I'm not a java programmer)

Comment: Yes it makes sense as part of an authorization concept. I could check if the current user is allowed to see the data with id=1.

Comment: @dodiddone: What is your plan to accomplish that? Wouldn't you need another table with user permissions in regards to the specific records from the Entity class?

Comment: added an example implementation.

Comment: @Olaf yes, that is correct, i simplified the example, i additional entities with user permissions etc.